# Is there an English word equivalent to the Cambodian word "oudom'kati"?

Tags: word-request

In Cambodian language, we have a word "oudom'kati" which means a supreme idea about what is truthfully right to do things regardless of self interest and regardless of an intention to please someone.

Do you have a single English word for that meaning?

Comment: Could you please give an example to better understand your context of "right"

Comment: Your question is not clear and there could be many English words depending on context. Context, please.

Answer (score 1):

We would probably call that concept 'morality'. If an action is right, we describe it as 'moral'. If an action is wrong, we describe it as 'immoral'.

Of course, everyone has a different idea of which actions are moral, and which are immoral. This branch of philosophical thought is called 'ethics'.

Answer (score 1):

Thai has a similar word, อุดมคติ (read "udomkhati"), which seems to have the same meaning, judging from the meaning you give in the question.

The best English word for it for all intents and purposes is ***ideal***.

Here is its definition by [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ideal):

> **[ideal](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ideal)**
>   Pronunciation: /ʌɪˈdɪəl/, /ʌɪˈdiːəl/
>
> adjective
>   1. Satisfying one’s conception of what is perfect; most suitable
>   2. [attributive] Existing only in the imagination; desirable or perfect but not likely to become a reality
>
> noun
>   1. A person or thing regarded as perfect
>   1.1. A standard or principle to be aimed at